# Insert tag in loop javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, safari

I want to insert the p tag after each rect tag but unfortunately when I used appendChild the p tag is insert into the rect tag and not after:

**JS code**:

```
$("#id_svg .nv-series-0 rect").each(function(index){ 

var line = document.createElement("p");
  line.className = "line";
  line.innerHTML = '|';


this.appendChild(line);

)}
```

**I had as a result:**
** html Code:**

```
<svg id="id_svg">
    <g class="nv-series-0">
        <rect class="nv-bar positive">
            <p class="line">|</p>
        </rect>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why not use jQuery? `$(this).append('<p class="line">|</p>')`?

Comment: Also, if you're only seeing one `p` output, then you only have one result from `#id_svg .nv-series-0 rect`

Comment: have you tryied using this.parent().appendChild(.....) ?

Comment: no I have several rect tags but I put an example of my code with a single rect tag. My problem is that I want to have the p tag after the rect tag and not in it. Like that <rect> </rect> <p> </p>
PS: I used the append function but I had the same problem
thank you for your reply

Comment: You don't need JS to add a `|` after each element in a list. CSS can do it with a pseudo-element : `rect:after { content : "|"; }`

Comment: thank you for your reply Jeremy Thille but i put the character | to simplify my code. actually the p tag is with several attributes (x, y, tronsform ...) is that it is not possible with css :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Element.insertAdjacentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement) instead of appendChild (which inserts it as a *child* inside).

```
this.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', line);
```

Comment: But it's overkill. It can be done easily with CSS alone (see my comment above)

Comment: thank you for your reply Jeremy Thille but i put the character | to simplify my code. actually the p tag is with several attributes (x, y, tronsform ...) is that it is not possible with css :) @JeremyThille